# Vertical middle with table-cell

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I'm trying to centering my paragraph with table, table-cell and vertical-align. For some reason, it doesn't work. Check my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/5yj652u6/) please.

html

```
<div class="a">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
  <div class="b">
    <p>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: 334px;
  background: red;
}

.a > * {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: you're applying the vertical-align to the paragraph and not the table cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k73xfayx/   here

The *outer* element has to have `display: table`, the inner ones `table-cell`

I put another DIV around your img (class c) to get that structure: One surrounding DIV (a), two DIVs inside that (c and b), one of them containing the img, one a p-Tag with text.

Comment: Also note the you cannot vertical align a floated element.

Comment: yes, I also erased quite a few things from the original CSS that were superfluous that I didn't mention in the answer above

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not seem to include any <`table`> tag at all. 
I am sorry if I have misinterpreted your question.

If you have changed it, then could you please edit your question and post your code's previous version in it. 
This will help people having a similar question.

This is what I currently see:

```
<div class="a">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
  <div class="b">
    <p>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Styling:

```
.a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: 334px;
  background: red;
}

.a > * {
  float: left;
}
```